# What is the mathematical meaning of $xx^T$

Tags: vector-spaces

Assume x is a n by 1 column vector, then , it is easily known that $x^Tx$ is the sum of squares. When calculate $xx^T$, it will give you a n by n matrix. I am wondering what is the mathematical meaning of such results.

Comment: If $x$ is length $1,$ the matrix $I - 2 x x^T$ gives a reflection, anything orthogonal to $x$ stays where it is, but $x$ goes to $-x.$

Comment: For real vectors $x^\top x$ is the length of $x$ squared. Does that count as a "mathematical meaning"?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ has length 1, then $xx^T$ is the orthogonal projection on the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (endowed with the canonical scalar product) generated by $x$.

Comment: Could you please clarify: (i) orthogonal projection of what?, (ii) is $x$ is a vector then what do we mean by "subspace generated by $x$"? do we not need at least 2 vectors in order to get a subspace?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$xx^T$ encodes all pairs $x_ix_j$ in the matrix that's formed. This is commonly used for calculating [Covariance matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

$x$ and $x^T$ are actually matrices which represent linear maps from one vector space to another and their multiplication is the same as composition of the corresponding linear maps. In your case $x$ is a map from 1 dimensional to n (the length of the column) dimensional space and $x^T$ is just the opposite (from n dimensional to 1 dimensional). Or the number of columns is the dimension of the 'starting' space and the number of rows - the dimension of the 'ending' space. Now if you compose the 2 maps (multiply $xx^T$) you should get linear map from n to n dimensional space, which should be represented by $n$ x $n$ matrix. Same logic applied to $x^Tx$ shows you why you get just a number.